# How to detect lanes using videocapture in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am new to python and opencv. I have a image of a road that detect the lanes. Now i am facing issue when trying to detect the lanes on the road from a video.

So far, it can detect the lanes from an image. I have tried using cv2.Videocapture method by putting it in a while loop but it is not working. The output just show a static image. The video is not running Below is the current output
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy


vidCap = cv2.VideoCapture('test2.mp4')
success, image = vidCap.read()
while success:
    success, img = vidCap.read()
    #img = cv2.imread('road png.PNG')
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    th, bw = cv2.threshold(gray, 170, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    bw = imclearborder(bw)
    RemoveTop(bw, round(bw.shape[0] * 0.6))
    RemoveTriangle(bw)
    bw = bwareaopen(bw, 800)
    blueMask = img.copy()
    blueMask[:, :] = (255, 0, 0)
    cv2.copyTo(blueMask, bw, img)
    cv2.imshow('Output', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I expect output to detect the the lanes on a video

Comment: Please include your (nonfunctional) code where you're working with cv2.Videocapture. We can't tell you what's wrong if you only show us the working parts. You can also remove RemoveTop, RemoveTriange and bwareaopen from your question as they are not necessary for [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry for that. I have uploaded the code i m working with

Comment: Or you can just replace cv2.waitkey(0) to cv2.waitKey(1) and remove the statement cv2.destroyAllWindows() or put it outside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

It was a simple solution.

```
    cv2.imshow('Output', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
vidCap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```